# kdb left join issue

Tags: join, left-join, kdb

I am trying to join two tables in KDB on the column INST.

```
src lj `INST xkey map
```

The resulting table should only return rows that have INST in both table (around 300,000 rows) src(about 600,000 rows) and table src(about 2,000 rows) but it is returning rows for every row in src.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it to join properly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
distinct map lj `INST xkey src
```

See explanation below.

> "it is returning rows for every row in src."

lj is behaving as expected: it takes every row from the left table and then joins on additional values from the right table where there is a match on the keyed column. If there is no match it appends null values in that row. E.g.

```
q)show t1: ([]sym:`GOOG`AAPL`MSFT; size: 3?100.; quant: 3?1000)
sym  size     quant
-------------------
GOOG 40.66642 908
AAPL 17.80839 360
MSFT 30.17723 522
q)show t2: ( [sym:`GOOG`MSFT] currency: `EUR`USD )
sym | currency
----| --------
GOOG| EUR
MSFT| USD
q)t1 lj t2
sym  size     quant currency
----------------------------
GOOG 40.66642 908   EUR
AAPL 17.80839 360
MSFT 30.17723 522   USD
```

ij (inner join) will exclude rows with no match on the keyed column:

```
q)t1 ij t2
sym  size     quant currency
----------------------------
GOOG 40.66642 908   EUR
MSFT 30.17723 522   USD
```

The q-sql statement:

```
map lj `INST xkey src
```

is equivalent to the SQL statement:

```
select * from map Left join src ON map.INST = [src].INST
```

If you also want only distinct rows then you may need something like:

```
distinct map lj `INST xkey src
```

since

> For a table, distinct returns the distinct rows

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#distinct

As Adam says, you also have to be careful with columns with identical names that are not being used to create the join.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ij` instead of `lj`. `lj` is essentially the same as SQL's left join. `ij` is essentially the same as SQL's inner join, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: That still does not return the results I need. I am trying to reproduce this SQL code
 `select distinct * from map
    Left join
    src
   ON map.INST = [src].INST`
@simon-major

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason ij wasn't working for you is because src and map have other columns with the same name.

Take this schema for example:

```
q)src:([INST:1 2 3 4] b:`a`b`c`d)
q)map:([INST:1 3 4] b:`1`2`3;c:`x`y`z)
```

Performing `ij` on these:

```
q)src ij map
INST| b c
----| ---
1   | 1 x
3   | 2 y
4   | 3 z
```

Here we can see that the result has taken the value of `b` from the map table.

To get around this you could rename the columns in each table to represent their source table, except the column you want to join on.

You can use this function:

```
q)rename_cols:{[tbl_name;key_col;cur_col] if[key_col~cur_col;:cur_col]; :`$tbl_name,".",(string cur_col) }
```

To edit the tables:

```
q)src:(rename_cols["src";`INST;] each cols src) xcol src;
q)map:(rename_cols["map";`INST;] each cols map) xcol map;
q)src
INST| src.b
----| -----
1   | a
2   | b
3   | c
4   | d
q)map
INST| map.b map.c
----| -----------
1   | 1     x
3   | 2     y
4   | 3     z
```

Now:

```
q)src ij map
INST| src.b map.b map.c
----| -----------------
1   | a     1     x
3   | c     2     y
4   | d     3     z
```

`INST=2` is missing because it is not present in both tables but you get each column from both tables.

Hopefully this is what you need.